# Using OpenSSL to decrypt hybrid encryption (AES + PKI)

Tags: openssl, aes, rsa, openssh

I have my public key and private key in the OpenSSH format. My public key starts with `ssh-rsa AAAA` and my private key starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEow`; just to give you an idea of the key format.

I have a python script that uses external libraries to perform hybrid encryption. The process looks like this:

Input:  `File To Encrypt and RSA Public Key --> Python Script`

Output: `Encrypted File and AES Key File`. This `AES` key file is encrypted again using the RSA public key from above.

So basically, the python script generates a random hash and uses that as a symmetric key to encrypt the file as AES and again uses the provided RSA key to encrypt the AES key into a file.

The real question is that, I am trying to troubleshoot my python script and I am trying to use the OpenSSL tool to test out the decryption part. I read somewhere that I need a `.pem` key so I transformed my existing key like this:

`openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.private -outform pem > id_rsa.pem`

and then I go after this to extract out the AES key from the file and get this error:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey id_rsa.pem -in aes.key -out key.bin
RSA operation error
86144:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:267:
86144:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c:614:
```

Am I using the OpenSSL tool the wrong way in some way? Do I have to have a `.pem` file? When considering about providing sugegstions, please suggest me how would I use the decrypted AES key to again decrypt the original file using AES decryption.

Comment: PEM is a general purpose format used for many things. For _most_ `openssl` commandline operations that use asymmetric keys (which is only a fraction) you do need the key(s) in file(s) in one of several PEM formats, but not some others (like Tectia or PUTTY); an _OpenSSH_ private key, unless you use(d) the 6.5+ 'new' format, is already in one of OpenSSL's 'legacy' formats and is compatible without any change. (Note an OpenSSH _public_ key is not, but the public key can always be recovered from the private key.) ...

Comment: ... There are a huge number of hybrid AES-RSA encryption schemes (probably thousands) so without specs and/or details about your code and the 'external libraries' it is unlikely this can be answered -- and anyway, StackOverflow questions (unlike some other stacks) are generally expected to [include an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)